# Change the evaluator within a switch statement

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

Is there a way, in a 'switch' to modify the variable you are evaluating on, and get it to change the match?

```
$var = "a"
switch ($var){

    "a" {Write-Host "1st match for 'a'"}
    "b" {Write-Host "1st match for 'b'"}
    "a" {Write-Host "2nd match for 'a'"; $var = "b" ; continue}
    "b" {Write-Host "2st match for 'b'"}
}
```

I would love to be able to get the above to match:

1st match for 'a'
2nd match for 'a'
2nd match for 'b'

```
$Destination = "vmstores:\vcsa@443\Training\Local-B\David" #is a param of my function, which could be a bunch of different types of object.

$DestinationType = $Destination.GetType().Name

    switch ($DestinationType){
        "String" {
            if ((Test-Path $Destination) -eq $true){
                if ((Get-Item $Destination).GetType().Name -eq "DatastoreFolderImpl"){
                    $DestinationType = "DatastoreFolderImpl"
                    if ((Test-Path $Destination.Insert($Destination.Length,"\").Insert(($Destination.Length)+1,$SourceVMXShort)) -eq $true){
                    Write-Warning "Destination File exists..."
                    $DestinationExists = $true
                    }
                }
                elseif ((Get-Item $Destination).GetType().Name -eq "DatastoreFileImpl"){
                    $DestinationType = "DatastoreFileImpl"
                    Write-Warning "Destination File exists..."
                    $DestinationExists = $true
                }
            }
             ; continue
        }
        "DirectoryInfo" {
            if ((Test-Path $Destination.Insert($Destination.Length,"\").Insert(($Destination.Length)+1,$SourceVMXShort)) -eq $true){
                Write-Warning "Destination File exists..."
                $DestinationExists = $true
            }
            ; break
        }
        "FileInfo" {
            if ((Test-Path $Destination) -eq $true){
                Write-Warning "Destination File exists..."
                $DestinationExists = $true
            }
            ; break
        }
        "DatastoreFileImpl" {
            if ((Test-Path $Destination) -eq $true){
                Write-Warning "Destination File exists..."
                $DestinationExists = $true
            }
            ; break
        }
        "DatastoreFolderImpl" {
            if ((Test-Path $Destination.Insert($Destination.Length,"\").Insert(($Destination.Length)+1,$SourceVMXShort)) -eq $true){
                Write-Warning "Destination File exists..."
                $DestinationExists = $true
            }
            ; break
        }
        "NasDatastoreImpl" {
            New-PSDrive -Name "DestMount" -Root \ -PSProvider VimDatastore -Datastore $Destination | Out-Null
            if ((Test-Path ("DestMount:").insert(10,"\").Insert(11,$SourceVMXShort)) -eq $true){
                Write-Warning "Destination File exists..."
                $DestinationExists = $true
            }
            $Destination = ("DestMount:").insert(10,"\")
            ; break
        }
        "VMFSDatastoreImpl" {
            New-PSDrive -Name "DestMount" -Root \ -PSProvider VimDatastore -Datastore $Destination | Out-Null
            if ((Test-Path ("DestMount:").insert(10,"\").Insert(11,$SourceVMXShort)) -eq $true){
                Write-Warning "Destination File exists..."
                $DestinationExists = $true
            }
            $Destination = ("DestMount:").insert(10,"\")
            ; break
        }

    }
```

As you can see, it would be more elegant if i could update the $DestinationType so i could re-use the statement in the other switch blocks, rather than the extra 'ifs'

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think you can change the `switch` statements variable mid check, you can do nested `switch` statements.  This code gives your requested output:

```
$var = "a"
switch ($var){
    "a" {Write-Host "1st match for 'a'"}
    "b" {Write-Host "1st match for 'b'"}
    "a" {Write-Host "2nd match for 'a'"
            $var = "b" 
            switch ($var) {
                "b" {Write-Host "2st match for 'b'"}
            } #End sub-switch
        } #End "A" check
} #End Primary switch
```

Now, I'm not sure what your overall goal is, there might be better ways to do this with functions and such.

Edit after updated question and comments:

From looking at the updated code, you can pull the one if statement that sets `$DestinationExists = $true`.  You might be able to reorganize your `if` statements so they only show up once.  Unfortunately, there is no way to get the switch statement to change the variable mid-switch.  From your comment, maybe you can add an extra parameter that will dictate the type, so you can us one large switch statement based off the type.  Something like this:

```
switch ($DataType) {
    "String" {<#Things to do if string#>}
    "OtherTypes" {<#Continue like this#>}
}#End Switch ($DataType)
```

I think at that point though, I would start using Parameter Sets.  Here is a blog describing about [Parameter Sets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/12/23/powershell-v2-parametersets.aspx)

Comment: i am writing a function, and one of the params could be a few types of objects, of which a string is one. if it matches 'string' then i want to change the value of the variable i am switching on, so i dont have to write extra 'ifs' in my statement blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat convoluted way to do it. Note that the example code is similar but not the same as the code in OP.

```
add-type @"

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;

public class PSVarEnumeration : IEnumerable
{
    private ScriptBlock _getterScript;

    public PSVarEnumeration(ScriptBlock getterScript)
    {
        _getterScript = getterScript;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
       return (IEnumerator) GetEnumerator();
    }

    public PSVarEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new PSVarEnumerator(_getterScript);
    }
}

public class PSVarEnumerator : IEnumerator
{
    private ScriptBlock _getterScript;
    bool areDone = false;

    // position isn't used for anything
    int position = -1;

    public PSVarEnumerator(ScriptBlock getterScript)
    {
        _getterScript = getterScript;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (!areDone) {
          if (Current != null) {
            position++;
            return true;
          } else {
            areDone = true;
            return false;
          }
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        position = -1;
        areDone = false;
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get
        {
            return Current;
        }
    }

    public Object Current
    {
        get
        {
            Collection<PSObject> results = _getterScript.Invoke();
            return results[0];
        }
    }
}

"@

$mySwitcher ="a"
$mySwitcherScript = {$mySwitcher}
$var = new PSVarEnumeration ( $mySwitcherScript)

switch ($var){

    "a" {Write-Host "1st match for 'a'"}
    "b" {Write-Host "1st match for 'b'"}
    "a" {Write-Host "2nd match for 'a'"; $mySwitcher = "b" ; continue}
    "b" {Write-Host "2nd match for 'b'"; $mySwitcher = $null}
}

<#
Output I get is:

1st match for 'a'
2nd match for 'a'
1st match for 'b'
2nd match for 'b'

#>
```